# Jquery animation positioning incorrectly an element, i want it on the side while animation show it bottom

Tags: jquery, html

I want to add an element on the side of other, so, i used a span element for do this.
The problem is that i want animate it with jquery and during the animation, the element is positioned bottom instead on the side (when the animation finish, it's correctly placed on the side).

this is the code

```
<div>Name<input id="name"/></div>
<div>Username <input id="user"/></div>
<button id="registerButton">Send -></button>


<script>
$('#registerButton').click(function() {       
    if($('#name').val().length<3) {                             
        $('#name').after($('<span id="warning">At least 3 chars</span>'));      
        $('#warning').hide();
        $('#warning').show(400);
    }                              
});
</script>
```

The warning should appear near the "name" element, but during the animation it appears bottom :(

Comment: I tested your code in http://jsfiddle.net/F2r2y/1/ the waring appends on the left side of #name so I suppose the problem is in your css. Maby you have set a width to the parent div

Comment: i tryied to delete all the css rules, the problem remain

Answer (score 0):

i can proof Ziinloander's answer. in webkit it does allready what you want, it depends on how much space is in your markup made by css.

Comment: on jsfiddle all works fine, but when i try on a "normal" web page the problem happen

Comment: does it still do this if 
`<div style="width:300px; border: 1px solid #000">
    <div>Name<input id="name"/></div>
    <div>Username <input id="user"/></div>
    <button id="registerButton">Send -></button>
</div>`

Comment: just to test where your problem comes from, you can wrap your existing markup into a `<div style='width:400px'> your markup </div>`. this says your browser it should hold some more space for your elements and so you can see if your problems come from wrong given size (even you could find out how much you need) via css for your complete animation with input fields together.

Comment: already done, but the problem persist..Can it depend on the version of jquery imported? I import it from google servers, maybe jsfiddle uses a newest version that solved this sort of "bug"

Comment: this can not come from jQuery, jQuery is using css rules as you would use by yourself too, there is not tricky extra they have. So if its not possible with CSS rules you cant do it with jQuery, but you could use the dynamic behavior of javascript with jQuery to hide wrong visual effects. In example to hide the element until it reaches its full size if some smaler visual parts of it would break your layout while animation.
I suggest to check again and again whats wrong with the css.

Comment: Edit you question and give us some code snippet of your css for this elements

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#registerButton').click(function() {       
    if($('#name').val().length<3) {                             
        if($('#warning').length == 0) {
            $('#name').after($('<span id="warning" style="display:none">At least 3 chars</span>'));
        }
        $('#warning').show(400);
    } else {
        $('#warning').hide();
    }                             
});
```